# How can i remove different items on same page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

how can i remove different items on same page without reloading page
like i want to remove some items and leave the rest

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").remove();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<p>remove this paragraph</p><button>close</button>
<p>leave this paragraph</p><button>close</button>
<p>remove this paragraph</p><button>close</button>
<p>leave this paragraph</p><button>close</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So when you click a button, you want to remove the paragraph before it? How about the button itself, should that disappear as well? And why do you have buttons after paragraphs where the text says "leave this paragraph"? And what do you mean by "without reloading page"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to remove the previous paragraph of the button and the button as well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $( this ).prev('p').remove();
    $( this ).remove();
  });
});
```

Demo there: https://codepen.io/aureliendebord/full/vYNqdrw

Answer (score -1):

well, you need to change the html to target the items for which you want to add a custom `class` for example:

```
<p>remove this paragraph</p><button>close</button>
<p>leave this paragraph</p><button>close</button>
<p class="item-to-remove">remove this paragraph</p><button>close</button>
<p>leave this paragraph</p><button>close</button>
```

so you need to change the CSS selector in the javascript as well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".item-to-remove").remove();
  });
});
```